# iMessage entries appearing in wrong order

Tags: iphone

When using iMessage my entries are not being shown in the order in which they are sent and received.  For example, instead of getting the following:

```
Sent 1
    Received 1
Sent 2
    Received 2
Sent 3
    Received 3
```

I get the following:

```
Sent 1
Sent 2
Sent 3
    Received 1
    Received 2
    Received 3
```

How can I make the messages appear in proper "chat" order?

Comment: no one answers me :((((

Comment: You'll have to be patient, the question needs re-opening and that isn't something I can do on my own.  Once it is open, then give it time for people to answer.

Comment: I can confirm this is still happening as of OS X 10.8.5, with messages sent from iOS 7.0.4. For example, today one conversation shows as `Sent 2, Sent 1, Received 1`. The messages were about 40 minutes apart, and with someone in the same time zone. Apple squashed Messages out-of-order bugs in [10.8.3](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5612) and [10.8.4](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5730), but apparently further bugs persist.

Answer (score 3):

The entries should be displayed in time stamp order.  That fact that your are not just occasionally wrong but seemingly always wrong suggests that you or the receiving end has a problem with their date and time settings.

If one of your phones is out by just a few minutes, I would expect this problem only to crop up if you are replying to each other quite quickly.  If many messages can go by before switching from sender to receiver, then there could be a wider gap.

Check out `Settings > General > Date & Time` and check if you or the other phone have manually set a date or time that could be different from each other.  If you both use `Set Automatically` it should prevent these problems. Check your timezone also.

Answer (score 1):

Many users use this technology to get their iMessages back to normal, so I want to share them with you.

First, open Settings, then click General -> Date & Time. Then, turn off the switch next to the auto setup - when the switch is on the left, you will know that it is off.

Now open the application switcher and close the messaging application. On iPhone 8 or earlier, double-click the Home button and then swipe up and down the Messaging app.
On iPhone X, swipe up from the bottom of the screen to open the app switcher. Then, hold down the preview of the messaging app until the red minus button appears in the top left corner of the app preview. Finally, click the red minus button to close the messaging application.

Now reopen the messaging app on the iPhone - your iMessages should be in the correct order! Now you can go back to Settings -> General -> Date & Time and reopen the automatic settings.

If this method fails, don't worry, there are other [ways](https://www.fonecope.com/fix-iphone-messages-out-of-order.html).

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. In reference to your last sentence, can I suggest that if you're aware of *other* ways to resolve this issue that you should also add them to your answer?

Comment: Hello, Monomeeth. For other methods I said, it is a FoneCope system recovery software. I used it once under the recommendation of a friend. I think it works well, at least it solved my problem. But I am hesitant to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Having seen this happen just recently, Stuffe's answer would appear to be the correct explanation of the symptom...

The fix was simply to restart the affected device.

That was presumably sufficient to make it check NNTP for the correct time again.